# mongodb sharded collection query failed: setShardVersion failed host

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have encountered a problem after adding a shard to mongodb cluster
.

I did the following operations:
   1. deploy a mongodb cluster with primary shard named 'shard0002'(10.204.8.155:27010) for all databases.
   2. for some reason I removed it and add a new shard of different host (10.204.8.100:27010, was automaticlly named shard0002 too)  after migrating finished.
   3. then add another shard (the one removed in step 1), named 'shard0003'
   4. executing query on a sharded collection.
   5. the following errors appeared:

mongos> db.count.find()
error: {
        "$err" : "setShardVersion failed host: 10.204.8.155:27010 { errmsg: \"exception: gotShardName different than what i had before  before [shard0002]  got [shard0003] \", code: 13298, ok: 0.0 }",
        "code" : 10429
}

I tried to rename the shardname, but it's not allowed.
mongos> use config
mongos> db.shards.update({_id: "shard0003"}, {$set: {_id: "shard_11"}})
Mod on _id not allowed

I have also tried to remove it, draining stared but processing seems hung up.
what can I do ?

------------------------
lastupate (24/02/2014 00:29)
  I found the answer on google.  since mongod has it's own cache for mongod configuration, just restart the sharded mongod process, the problem will be fixed.

Comment: well, I fix it by exchanging the hosts mapped to shard002 and shard003.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's about administration and configuration of MongoDB, not about software development. I voted to migrate this question to http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: sorry, Philipp, this is my first post and didn't know how to migrate the topic, what's the step ?

Comment: You can't migrate it yourself. 4 other users with enough reputation will have to vote too.